# Emmett и notepad++

Tags: css, вёрстка, notepad++, редактор-текста

Доброго времени суток. Долгое время я использовал notepad++ в связке с emmett. Однако в последнее время раскрытие тегов стало тормозить при больших кусках кода. Потом я перешел на Atom, в котором с этим делом все хорошо. Однако сама скорость работы атома несколько медленней, чем работа того же нотепада. Собственно вопрос. Можно ли ускорить работу emmett в связки с notepad++? Ну или посоветуйте редактор для верстки  с возможность работать с файлами по ftp и подобием эмметта. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pspad](http://www.pspad.com/) + emmet. много лет сижу - ненарадуюсь

сейчас вам будут всякие модные сублимы советовать, но если notepad++ вам роднее, то они вам не подойдут

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, Sublime Text 3 в связке с тем же эмметом. Работает шустро. Сам переходил с плюсов на него

Comment: Работа с FTP - адская боль. еще и за деньги.

Comment: Ну... Человек переходит с ноутпад++. Считаю достойной заменой саблайм. Нюансы работы в виде фтп нивелируются нормальным фтп-клиентом. Не вижу трудностей